# ffmpeg log missing "dup" and "drop" key-value pairs

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, linux, output

For some reason, my ffmpeg output log does not show **dup** and **drop** key-value pairs.

expect:

```
...
frame=563 fps=138 q=23.0 size=13056kB time=00:00:09.42 bitrate=11346.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=0 speed= 2.3x
...
```

running the following:

```
~/bin/ffmpeg -i INPUT.mkv \
    -t 00:00:10.000 \
    -c:v libx264 -crf 15 -preset veryfast \
    OUTPUT.mkv 2>&1|tee ffmpeg.log
```

results in this output instead:

```
...
frame=  563 fps=138 q=23.0 size=   13056kB time=00:00:09.42 bitrate=11346.8kbits/s speed= 2.3x
frame=  600 fps=134 q=-1.0 Lsize=   16199kB time=00:00:09.98 bitrate=13294.4kbits/s speed=2.23x
video:16095kB audio:92kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:4kB muxing overhead: 0.077694%
[libx264 @ 0x55d5711efac0] frame I:3     Avg QP:15.71  size:227164
...
```

or running:

```
~/bin/ffmpeg -f v4l2 \
    -framerate 60 -video_size 1920x1080 \
    -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video0 \
    -c:v libx264 -crf 15 -preset veryfast \
    -tune film -profile:v high -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    -color_primaries 1 -color_trc 1 -colorspace 1 \
    -dst_range 1 -color_range 2 \
    OUTPUT.mkv 2>&1|tee ffmpeg.log
```

gives:

```
...
frame=  880 fps= 60 q=23.0 size=   64512kB time=00:00:14.31 bitrate=36910.3kbits/s speed=0.977x
frame=  911 fps= 60 q=23.0 size=   64512kB time=00:00:14.83 bitrate=35626.4kbits/s speed=0.978x
```

system info

- OS: Linux Debian 10 (buster) x86_64
- tested with two versions of ffmpeg:

1) Debian package

```
$ ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 4.1.4-1~deb10u1 built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
```

2) compiled for myself

```
$ ~/bin/ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version N-97910-g88567a2 built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
```

using `-loglevel debug` and `ffv1`

```
~/bin/ffmpeg -i INPUT.mkv \
    -t 00:00:10.000     \
    -acodec  copy       \
    -vcodec  ffv1       \
    -level 1 -coder 1 -context 1 -g 1 \
    -loglevel debug     \
    OUTPUT.mkv 2>&1|tee ffmpeg.log
```

result: unable to find a single occurrence of the word "drop" in log.txt file

How to output the missing "**dup**" and "**drop**" in my log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no frames are dupped or dropped, then those fields are not printed.

If you need a definitive statement, add `-progress filename` to print progress report to a file and search for `dup_frames` and `drop_frames`.